# DAX: different behaviour Calculate( Calculate (...)) vs Calculate( Var)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to write in a succinct and readable fashion a measure which expresses a count in a previous month where weekends are filtered out.

I have 4 measures. The results are expressed in this table.

| Month | TestMeasure | Test2 | Test 3 | Test 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| October | 4426 |  | 4426 |  |
| November | 221 | 4426 | 221 | 4426 |
| December |  | 221 |  | 221 |

The first measure gives the count for the current month.

```
TestMeasure = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Metingen[TempOverschrijding]), FILTER(Datum,NOT(Datum[Weekdag] IN {"zaterdag","zondag"})))
```

The second uses the first and calculates it for the previous month.

```
Test2 = CALCULATE([TestMeasure],  PARALLELPERIOD(Datum[Datum],-1,month))
```

So far so good. Next, I tried to combine 1,2 into one measure. Test 4 is not pretty but it works with 2 layers of calculate().

```
Test 4 = CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(COUNTA(Metingen[TempOverschrijding]), FILTER(Datum,NOT(Datum[Weekdag] IN {"zaterdag","zondag"})))
    ,  PARALLELPERIOD(Datum[Datum],-1,month)
    )
```

Test 3 I tried to capture the inner calculate in a var and return the outer calculate over that var.

```
Test 3 = 
VAR TO_NoWeekends = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Metingen[TempOverschrijding]), FILTER(Datum,NOT(Datum[Weekdag] IN {"zaterdag","zondag"})))
return CALCULATE(TO_NoWeekends,  PARALLELPERIOD(Datum[Datum],-1,month))
```

However it looks like my parallel period is ignored here.

- Can someone explain to me why or what I am missing?
- Is there a nicer way than Test 4 to get my intended results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a touch more succinct:

```
=
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA( Metingen[TempOverschrijding] ),
    NOT ( Datum[Weekdag] IN { "zaterdag", "zondag" } ),
    PARALLELPERIOD( Datum[Datum], -1, MONTH )
)
```